# Inserting shortcode function into php line

Tags: php

Im not much a php programmer but i need to edit one WordPress theme file so i can insert a php function which display ad banner exactly at below code location marked as -> **INSERT HERE THE SHORTCODE PHP** <- line 72

My php function that i need to insert over there in-between `<div class="banner-shortcode">` is:

`<?php if (function_exists ('adinserter')) echo adinserter (17); ?>`

But if i put it like that i get *Syntax error, unexpected T_STRING*

```
 <?php
if( get_theme_mod( 'penci_enable_featured_video_bg' ) && get_theme_mod( 'penci_featured_video_url' ) ) {
    get_template_part( 'inc/featured_slider/featured_video' );
} else {
    if ( get_theme_mod( 'penci_featured_slider' ) == true ) :
        $slider_style = get_theme_mod( 'penci_featured_slider_style' ) ? get_theme_mod( 'penci_featured_slider_style' ) : 'style-1';

        if( ( $slider_style == 'style-33' || $slider_style == 'style-34' ) && get_theme_mod( 'penci_feature_rev_sc' ) ) {
            $rev_shortcode = get_theme_mod( 'penci_feature_rev_sc' );
            echo '<div class="featured-area featured-' . $slider_style . '">';
            if( $slider_style == 'style-34' ): echo '<div class="container">'; endif;
            echo do_shortcode( $rev_shortcode );
            if( $slider_style == 'style-34' ): echo '</div>'; endif;
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            if ( get_theme_mod( 'penci_body_boxed_layout' ) && ! get_theme_mod( 'penci_vertical_nav_show' ) ) {
                if( $slider_style == 'style-3' ) {
                    $slider_style == 'style-1';
                } elseif( $slider_style == 'style-5' ) {
                    $slider_style == 'style-4';
                } elseif( $slider_style == 'style-7' ) {
                    $slider_style == 'style-8';
                } elseif( $slider_style == 'style-9' ) {
                    $slider_style == 'style-10';
                } elseif( $slider_style == 'style-11' ) {
                    $slider_style == 'style-12';
                } elseif( $slider_style == 'style-13' ) {
                    $slider_style == 'style-14';
                } elseif( $slider_style == 'style-15' ) {
                    $slider_style == 'style-16';
                } elseif( $slider_style == 'style-17' ) {
                    $slider_style == 'style-18';
                } elseif( $slider_style == 'style-29' ) {
                    $slider_style == 'style-30';
                } elseif( $slider_style == 'style-35' ) {
                    $slider_style == 'style-36';
                }
            }
            $slider_class = $slider_style;
            if( $slider_style == 'style-5' ) {
                $slider_class = 'style-4 style-5';
            } elseif ( $slider_style == 'style-30' ) {
                $slider_class = 'style-29 style-30';
            } elseif ( $slider_style == 'style-36' ) {
                $slider_class = 'style-35 style-36';
            }
            $data_auto = 'false';
            $data_loop = 'true';
            $data_res = '';

            if( $slider_style == 'style-7' || $slider_style == 'style-8' ){
                $data_res = ' data-item="4" data-desktop="4" data-tablet="2" data-tabsmall="1"';
            } elseif( $slider_style == 'style-9' || $slider_style == 'style-10' ){
                $data_res = ' data-item="3" data-desktop="3" data-tablet="2" data-tabsmall="1"';
            } elseif( $slider_style == 'style-11' || $slider_style == 'style-12' ){
                $data_res = ' data-item="2" data-desktop="2" data-tablet="2" data-tabsmall="1"';
            } elseif( in_array( $slider_style, array( 'style-31', 'style-32', 'style-35', 'style-36', 'style-37' ) ) ) {
                $data_next_prev = get_theme_mod( 'penci_enable_next_prev_penci_slider' ) ? 'true' : 'false';
                $data_dots = get_theme_mod( 'penci_disable_dots_penci_slider' ) ? 'false' : 'true';
                $data_res = ' data-dots="'. $data_dots .'" data-nav="'. $data_next_prev .'"';
            }

            if( get_theme_mod( 'penci_featured_autoplay' ) ): $data_auto = 'true'; endif;
            if( get_theme_mod( 'penci_featured_loop' ) ): $data_loop = 'false'; endif;
            $auto_time = get_theme_mod( 'penci_featured_slider_auto_time' );
            if( !is_numeric( $auto_time ) ): $auto_time = '4000'; endif;
            $auto_speed = get_theme_mod( 'penci_featured_slider_auto_speed' );
            if( !is_numeric( $auto_speed ) ): $auto_speed = '600'; endif;
            $open_container = '';
            $close_container = '';
            if( in_array( $slider_style, array( 'style-1', 'style-4', 'style-6', 'style-8', 'style-10', 'style-12', 'style-14', 'style-16', 'style-18', 'style-19', 'style-20', 'style-21', 'style-22', 'style-23', 'style-24', 'style-25', 'style-26', 'style-27', 'style-30', 'style-32', 'style-36', 'style-37' ) ) ):
                $open_container = '<div class="container"><div class="banner-shortcode">INSERT HERE THE SHORTCODE PHP</div>';
                $close_container = '</div>';
            endif;
            if( get_theme_mod( 'penci_enable_flat_overlay' ) && in_array( $slider_style, array( 'style-6', 'style-7', 'style-8', 'style-9', 'style-10', 'style-11', 'style-12', 'style-13', 'style-14', 'style-15', 'style-16', 'style-17', 'style-18', 'style-19', 'style-20', 'style-21', 'style-22', 'style-23', 'style-24', 'style-25', 'style-26', 'style-27', 'style-28' ) ) ): $slider_class .= ' penci-flat-overlay'; endif;

            echo '<div class="featured-area featured-' . $slider_class . '">' . $open_container;
            if( $slider_style == 'style-37' ):
                echo '<div class="penci-featured-items-left">';
            endif;
            echo '<div class="penci-owl-carousel penci-owl-featured-area"'. $data_res .'data-style="'. $slider_style .'" data-auto="'. $data_auto .'" data-autotime="'. $auto_time .'" data-speed="'. $auto_speed .'" data-loop="'. $data_loop .'">';
            get_template_part( 'inc/featured_slider/' . $slider_style );
            echo '</div>';
            echo $close_container. '</div>';
        }
    endif;
    }
```

How to place it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line would be like this:

```
$open_container = '<div class="container"><div class="banner-shortcode">'. (function_exists('adinserter') ? adinserter(17) : '') .'</div>';
```

What I did is, I used the ternary operator to check whether `function_exists('adinserter')` is returning a true. If true, it would call the `adinserter(17)` function, which would return a string (maybe html I don't know) and this is being appended to the string in `$open_container` variable. Otherwise (if false), an empty string is appended.

Hope you got the idea

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing curly brackets

Comment: Curly brackets are not required unless the block consists of more than one statement.